# Can the Repository Pattern work well with Asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net

I've been using MVC for the last year and unfortunately I am stuck adding features to an existing web forms site. The site makes heavy use of inline SQL and it is kind of all over the place. Using an ORM is not going to happen either and wouldn't address the problem of keeping queries all in one place.

Can the Repository Pattern and Service layers also work well with classic asp.net web forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can work. But if your application already has SQL queries inside the .ASPX pages some major refactoring would be necessary. For example you could [configure your DI framework](http://joeoncode.com/post/Ninject-2-and-WebForms.aspx) to inject repositories into the pages and in the code behind call methods on those repositories that would return strongly typed objects that would be bound to server side controls such as a GridView inside the markup.

Actually before ASP.NET MVC comes out that's exactly what I was doing.

Comment: There's been a lot of programmers that have had a go at this site. So no refactoring to existing code would be done, at least not any time soon. This is more for when I program new features or sections. I think using ninject is already going to far :)

Answer (score 1):

These patterns are pretty much universal to most types of applications. I have used them in web applications and windows applications and I know they can be applied to mobile apps as well.

As Darin has mentioned the problem is the amount of work required to change the forms as it is essentially a rewrite. Sometimes the cost of refactoring just isn't worth it, it all depends on the project.

Comment: If I would go the repository route for queries what should my return type be? DataSet, DataTable, other?

Comment: Ok, I just found out that class files outside the App_Code folder will not compile, so scratch this idea. I think a move to a web application project is a much higher priority as you guys implied with the major refactoring.

Comment: It depends what you want, I prefer to have an object oriented representation of the model so I normally return objects. I would recommend you read up about Domain Driven Design as it fits in with the solution you are describing. I learned a lot by studying it.